# Why doesn't Stack Overflow have a chatroom like http://chat.superuser.com/?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, chat

I really found the chat rooms over on http://chat.superuser.com/ to be helpful. Why doesn't Stack Overflow implement this?

Comment: This should be on meta.stackoverflow, and I absolutely and completely agree with you.  :-D

Answer (score 6):

Timing; we're still rolling them out - simply stackoverflow has the biggest challenges so will be *last* ;p

For now, please come and join us on chat.meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 6):

Read the entire blog entry: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/super-user-chat-now-available/

> stackoverflow.com will be the last
> site to get chat because its immense
> volume presents the hardest challenge

Answer (score 2):

Try http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/