# Any soft release dates for Stack Overflow chat?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, chat

In this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65094/why-doesnt-stack-overflow-have-a-chatroom-like-http-chat-superuser-com/65097#65097) a few months ago, there is talk of eventually rolling out a Stack Overflow chat.

I'm curious, is there any kind of projected release date or anything on Stack Overflow chat?

Comment: I'm quite surprised that given the preponderance of URLs in that post that you didn't try the obvious one before asking this question :\

Comment: @drachenstern Not everyone is the curious type who'll just experiment with URLs and hope that it'll work. Likewise, the running assumption here was that the chat hadn't launched yet.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't intending to insult you - I was trying to point out that seeing all the URLs in a thread that says "It's not out yet" and then intuiting that one should mangle the URL and test is... well, not the first thing most people would try. This wasn't meant to paint you in a negative light.

Comment: @Grace the day you insult me is the day I call you out and ask you to meet me in chat. ;) ~~ You were totally right, I'm just astounded that it's been in the blog and all sorts of other places. Also, note the chatroom smacked me too ;)

Comment: @drachenstern 1- I noticed that you got smacked around 2- That second comment of mine was directed at Mark Rogers, not you, in response to a now-deleted comment. Though, at the same time, I was also not intending to insult you in this instance.

Comment: @Grace ~ Oh, ok ;)

Comment: @Mark Huh? What are you talking about? Chat is there a long time ago!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A soft release date might be impossible... so how about the [hard release date](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-overflow-chat-now-live/) of **October 15th, 2010**? ♪

It's live and you can find it [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Also, there's a link in the top navigation bar of each site

Comment: Also there's literally hundreds of comments on meta and SO that reference it. And answers. And questions even.

Comment: @drachenstern Well, it's not like everyone on SO frequents meta. I just meant "when you need to get to it in the future, you can click this handy link", not "you should've known, the link is right there"

Answer (score 3):

Well, to be fair to the OP, Stack Overflow is the only place where we do not have chat house ads enabled -- which increases the visibility of chat substantially.

[image]

Comment: Does that mean we need to submit a bug report so you can status-denied it on account of 6-8 weeks? ;)

Comment: @drach we're a little afraid to deploy the chat ad on Stack Overflow because it's so large..