# Why doesn't Stack Overflow have a "Chat" link like the rest of the sites?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

In the footer (bottom left corner) of *every* site in the network there is a "**Chat**" link, for example:

**ENGLISH LANGUAGE & USAGE**

> Tour
>
> Help
>
> **Chat <----**
>
> Contact
>
> Feedback
>
> Mobile
>
> Disable Responsiveness

Except the **Stack Overflow** page has no "Chat" link:

> Questions
>
> Jobs
>
> Developer Jobs Directory
>
> Salary Calculator
>
> Help
>
> Mobile
>
> Disable Responsiveness

Could somebody please explain why? I found [**this question**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65094/why-doesnt-stack-overflow-have-a-chatroom-like-http-chat-superuser-com) from 10 years ago.

Comment: Related: [Where did the Stack Overflow chat link go?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361536/4642212).